# Vim plugin for Java HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, vim

As of now I am using the Vim built-in SyntaxComplete for my editing.

I started my JavaEE project in Vim with Ant and went this way for a few weeks but Eclipse functionalities were lacking too much so I gave up for the Java part but I still use it for the other languages that my project requires.

I am not looking for a plugin that provides snippets but I would like to see my functions and variables smartly predicted.

I tried [JavaComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1785) but it was not working. I don't really like the idea of starting the whole Eclipse engine behind Vim as [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) does but if it's really worth it I could give it a try.

For the other languages, these settings in my vimrc are almost enough but for Javascript:

```
set nu
set autoindent
set nocompatible
set vb
syntax on
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete 
filetype plugin indent on
```

[Here is my complete vimrc](https://github.com/jggc/vim/blob/master/vimrc) if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've given up using vim for Java Web development some years ago, cause it really needs a lot of tooling support (Intellij IDEA is very nice). I've had more success using vim for developing Grails applications, but I feel that for Java I really want strong refactoring tools.

Having said that, if you really insist in using vim, here are some plugins that may help you:

- [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) - code hinting support for Java, JS, XML and more
- [html5.vim](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim) - improved HTML5 support
- [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) - improved JavaScript support
- [emmet-vim](http://mattn.github.io/emmet-vim/) - aka Zen Coding, speeds up HTML creation
- [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) - handy plugin to manipulate several types of surrounding marks (e.g.: quotes, brackets, parenthesis, HTML tags, etc)

Note that these plugins are probably helpful in any Web development scenario though, none of them are really specific for Java environments.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying out some of them right now. vim-javascript looks nice. I won't accept right now as I would like some more suggestions. And about syntastic, I did not install it yet but does it requires configuration to get it to work or is it all  functional out of the box?

Comment: @Johnride For some languages it works out of the box. For others, you may have to install a third party tool (see the [FAQ](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic#faq)).